# AC to DC converter circuit

Tags: power-supply, voltage, capacitor, current, resistors

[image]

This is an AC to DC converter.

From what I have simulated in LT spice software, when the R1 drops from 1k to maybe 5 ohms resistance, the output is oscillating and no longer smoothing to DC. I have tried changing the capacitor value and resistor value to simulate output for a 5 ohms load (R1) but no luck in smoothing to DC.

Question: What is the way to smooth the output of AC to DC if the load is small lets say (5 ohms rather than 1000 ohms)? Do make suggestions and I can simulate it to verify your results.

I have another schematic which is also a rectifier.

[image]

Question: **From your experience, is this safe to be built at home because when I simulate, the current in the capacitor spikes up to megaamps for a very short amount of time?**

[image]

Comment: Bigger capacitor.

Comment: @ Hearth  I have checked, but the output voltage for load is too small

Comment: for larger powers, *the way* in the modern world is to increase the frequency of V1. But you could also increase C1 a lot. As you have realized this gets difficult quickly, so you either postregulate with a linear regulator between C1 and R1 (inefficient, heat) or increase the frequency forming a *switch mode* converter.

Comment: Well, you're using an extremely large load (assuming this is line voltage) at just 5 ohms. If you want to use this simplistic sort of power supply, you're going to need an extremely large capacitor.

Comment: Maybe simulate longer than just 50ms?

Comment: If you want low ripple at high currents then you’ll need a big capacitor - back in they day before switch-mode was popular it would be common to see capacitors of 10,000 to 100,000uF in such applications.

Comment: use a transistor to multiply the capacitor by hfe.

Answer (score 6):

What you’re seeing in the first sim is *ripple*, and this will increase with load current: the filter capacitor is being discharged between AC cycles, then charged up again when the rectified AC peaks come in. The larger the cap, the smaller the ripple.

Typically, if ripple is a concern even with an adequately-sized filter cap, then a post-regulator will take care of it. Post-regulators can be linear or DC-DC type, the latter being more efficient.

The second simulation omits series resistances in the reactive components. In real life these resistances will limit the transients you’re seeing in the sim. So, yes, it’s relatively safe to build.

LTSpice is a good, accurate simulator. Nevertheless, for quick try-outs like these I recommend [Falstad](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/) which allows you to dynamically view and interact with the simulation.

Comment: (for the OP :)  Note that post-regulator won't help without a decent reservoir capacitor. Then it'll regulate anywhere up to the bottom of the ripple waveform.

Answer (score 4):

When you consider that the diode bridge simply inverts the negative-going portions of the input waveform into positives, it's clear that the output from the bridge is a series of positive "pulses", like this:

[image]

The capacitor across the bridge output charges during the peaks of these pulses. When the pulses of voltage from the bridge rectifier are greater than the capacitor's voltage, the capacitor simply charges up to that voltage.

There are intervals, though, between each peak, when the voltage from the bridge is lower than the capacitor's voltage, and during these intervals it will be the capacitor that provides current to any connected load. During those intervals, the capacitor's voltage will drop, as it discharges through the load:

[image]

The blue trace shows the capacitor initially charging (which is the cause of those huge "inrush" currents you experienced), and its voltage diminishing between each subsequent charge cycle.

*Any* connected load will cause the capacitor's voltage to "droop" like this, resulting in the ripple you have experienced. This ripple will always be present, and its amplitude will depend on the current demanded by the load. The larger the current drawn by the load, the quicker the capacitor discharges, and the larger the amplitude of ripple.

The brute-force solution is to increase the capacitance, so that it discharges less between each pulse, but this approach can never *completely* eliminate ripple. To combat ripple we use voltage regulators. A voltage regulator takes a varying input source of voltage, and outputs a fixed, steady voltage.

*Switching* regulators can take any input voltage and produce any output voltage. They are efficient but complicated. The simpler, *linear* regulator, will take your ripple-infested source and produce a steady output voltage, with these caveats:

- The input voltage must never drop below a certain minimum. That
  minimum is defined by the desired output voltage, and the "dropout"
  specification for the particular regulator being used:

  $$ V_{input} \geq V_{out} + V_{dropout} $$
- The regulator is essentially a self-varying resistance, that will
  dissipate power as any resistor does. It will deliver power to the
  load, but also dissipate some itself in doing so, and you must take
  care to keep the regulator's temperature within its limits.

In this next circuit, I used the ubiquitous 7805 regulator, to obtain a fixed 5V, with (very nearly) none of the ripple present at its input:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZNn68.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

However, the 7805 has a dropout voltage of 3V, meaning that if ever its input falls below 5V + 3V = 8V, the regulator cannot do its job. Look what happens when I reduce the capacitor C1, so that it discharges too much between each rectified pulse:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Frequency doubling makes T= 10ms and charging ripple if allowed to be 10% requires the load RC=8T or so. Thus if R=50 C=80ms/50ohms=1.6mF

All e-caps have ESR which may be <20us=ESR*C for low ESR types and ESR=0 gives unreal currents but for 10% Vripple, the peak current will be 10x the DC load.